# Blackberry Sound Graphic Analyser

Tags: blackberry

In my BB application I need to play/record sound and simultaneously show a Sound Graphic Analyser(as shown in image attached) within the application.I have searched forums but have found nothing significant.

[image]

I want to show graphics as shown when playing or recording music dependending upon the pitch of the sound. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no API in RIM SDK to obtain such data upon playing a media file. But you can analyze the sound file contents by yourself, draw diagram and implement "cursor" (vertical green line on your image) that will be based on the time passed after start of the sound playing.